# Could not find FirebaseUI widget error

Tags: javascript, firebase, authentication, web-applications, firebaseui

I am attempting to make a login screen using firebaseui auth for a single-page web app. I copied firebaseui's sample code to create the login screen:

```
<script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/firebaseui/3.0.0/firebaseui.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/firebaseui/3.0.0/firebaseui.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript">
  // FirebaseUI config.
  var uiConfig = {
    signInOptions: [
      // Leave the lines as is for the providers you want to offer your users.
      firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
      firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
    ]
  };

  // Initialize the FirebaseUI Widget using Firebase.
  var ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());
  // The start method will wait until the DOM is loaded.
  ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', uiConfig);
</script>
```

Then I just inserted a

```
<div id="firebaseui-auth-container'></div>
```

to load the login screen. The regular firebase stuff loads just fine, but the auth screen doesn't.
Here is the error I got:

```
Uncaught Error: Could not find the FirebaseUI widget element on the page.
```

I couldn't find this error anywhere else online, and I'm not sure what it means or why it is appearing. What should I do to make the auth screen load?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The error is thrown from here: https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/blob/cac4047490ed90b0d3d741d6deb8b28905f5db4b/javascript/widgets/authui.js#L481

Seems the html element cannot be found. Can you try to call `document.querySelector('#firebaseui-auth-container');` from console to confirm the element exist on that page?

Comment: hmm... I just tried doing the whole thing again, and now it works. I have no idea why, but it isn't throwing any errors now and it loads nicely. Thank you for the help anyways!

Comment: Ti, I have just tried that and it returned null. I don't get this too often, but it comes up quite a bit in our Sentry logs. Is there anything else I can do to help debug it?

Comment: @JamesBritton Did you add the firebaseui container tag in your html? You have to tell firebaseui where to render the widget.

Comment: @TiWang I am using [Firebase UI Web React](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web-react) which I don't believe mentions adding that, so I assume it's already implemented. Wondering if I need to rethink this design decision.

Answer (score 5):

Your code sample:

```
<div id="firebaseui-auth-container'></div>
```

contains inconsistent quotes, where the first is double, the second is single quotes. I believe you meant to code it as:

```
<div id="firebaseui-auth-container"></div>
```

or

```
<div id='firebaseui-auth-container'></div>
```